# How to make selected checkbox item?

Tags: android, json, android-alertdialog

I am getting response from server,and I use textview,and on textview's click listener I set alertdialog,where user can select multiple items,but when values from server via reponse,items are not selected see images below

[image]

[image]

```
public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        showDialog(0);
    }
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    return
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Languages")
                    .setMultiChoiceItems(_options, _selections, new DialogSelectionClickHandler())
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogButtonClickHandler())
                    .create();
}

public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected) {
        Log.i("ME", _options[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);
    }
}

public class DialogButtonClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked) {
        switch (clicked) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                spmrg.setText("");
                for (int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++)
                {
                    if(_selections[i])
                    {
                        if(spmrg.getText().toString().length()>0)
                        {
                            spmrg.setText(spmrg.getText().toString().trim()+","+_options[i]);
                        }else
                        {
                            spmrg.setText(_options[i]);
                        }
                    }

                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
protected void printSelectedPlanets(){
    for( int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++ ){
        Log.i( "ME", _options[ i ] + " selected: " + _selections[i] );
    }
}

        protected CharSequence[] _options = {"UnMarried","Widow/Widower","Divorcee","Separated"};
        protected boolean[] _selections = new boolean[_options.length];
```

Comment: Do you want to select the ones which appear on the EditText? Why not using something like a "performClick" on the creation of the dialog?

Comment: the string i am getting in martital stauts is using json

Comment: and whatever value i am getting using json,it is displaying in textview of marital status,but not selected in alert dialog view

Comment: "but when values from server via reponse,items are not selected" , what exactly you want to ask? not able to understand.

Comment: @Darpan brother i am getting values in my textview using json,but when i click on textview items are not seleceted in my alert dialog

Comment: @Darpan see my previous question and you will get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437248/org-json-jsonexception-index-3-out-of-range-0-3/27438130?noredirect=1#comment43317207_27438130

Comment: Sorry for my first comment, when I was writing that, you happened to explain what I asked. Btw, .setMultiChoiceItems(_options, _selections, I want to see how you have initialized `_optins` and `_selections`.

Comment: @Darpan see my edited question,at bottom i added two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you got 'unmarried' in your json object.

So, this is what you will do -

```
CharSequence[] _options = { "UnMarried", "Widow/Widower", "Divorcee",
                "Separated" };
        String[] valueFromJson = { "UnMarried", "Divorcee" }; // you will pass
                                                                // your
                                                                // value from
                                                                // JSON
                                                                // to this
                                                                // variable
        boolean[] isSelected = new boolean[_options.length];
        boolean[] _selections = new boolean[_options.length];

public boolean[] markChecked() {

        int[] locations = new int[valueFromJson.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < valueFromJson.length; i++) {
            int index = Arrays.asList(_options).indexOf(valueFromJson[i]);
            locations[i] = index;
            System.out.println(index + " " + valueFromJson[i]);

        }
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
            if (k< locations.length && locations[k] == i) {
                isSelected[i] = true;
                k++;
            } else {
                isSelected[i] = false;
            }
            System.out.println(isSelected[i]);
        }
        return isSelected;

    }
```

now  do this -

`.setMultiChoiceItems(_options, markChecked(), new DialogSelectionClickHandler())`

Comment: what does that mean? String[] valueFromJson = { "UnMarried", "Divorcee" }; // you will pass
                                                                // your
                                                                // value from
                                                                // JSON
                                                                // to this
                                                                // variable

Comment: this means that you just need to get values you will get in your response, (lets say you get 'UnMarried,Divorcee' in responce, then you will have to convert them into an array, and save value of that array in 'valueFromJson' array.

Comment: can i send you mail all files?

Comment: post it somewhere online or try to chat with me.. that will help.

Comment: i did but you are not there